# Regex replace in multiple files

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I need to replace all instances of a regex with another regex in multiple files that are in multiple directories under a root directory.

Example:
File Structure:

```
.
|---src
|   |---Module
|   |   |---someclass.cpp
|   |---main.cpp
|
|---include
    |---Module
        |---someclass.hpp
```

basically that but with more files and folders.

I need to search for the regex `\(std::vector<.*>` and replace all instances of it with `\(std::vector<.*> const&`
The tricky part seems to be making sure the content between `<` and `>` stays the same.

For example it would match `(std::vector<int>` and replace it with `(std::vector<int> const&`.
A more complex example would be:
Match: `(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>>`
Replace with: `(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> const&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that final ">" in your examples is the last ">" on each line then this should work:

```
find root -name '*.cpp' -print0 |
xargs -0 sed -i 's/\((std::vector<.*>\)\([^>]*$\)/\1 const\&\2/'
```

Try the sed on a single file and without the -i first, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
(std::vector<int>
(std::vector<int> foo
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>>
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> bar

$ sed 's/\((std::vector<.*>\)\([^>]*$\)/\1 const\&\2/' file
(std::vector<int> const&
(std::vector<int> const& foo
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> const&
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> const& bar
```

If there can be ">"s after the last one in your example then the solutions non-trivial, post some representative sample input and expected output.

Oh, what the heck, here's the non-trivial script:

```
$ cat file
(std::vector<int>
(std::vector<int> foo
(std::vector<int> with extra > in text
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>>
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> bar
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> and here is > again

$ awk -v FS= -v str="(std::vector<" '
BEGIN{ lgth=length(str) }
start=index($0,str) {
   cnt = 1
   for(i=(start+lgth);(i<=NF) && (cnt!=0);i++) {
      if ($i == "<") cnt++
      if ($i == ">") cnt--
   }
   $0 = substr($0,1,i-1) " const&" substr($0,i)
}1' file
(std::vector<int> const&
(std::vector<int> const& foo
(std::vector<int> const& with extra > in text
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> const&
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> const& bar
(std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> const& and here is > again
```

Do that inside a while loop:

```
find root -name '*.cpp' -print |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    awk -v FS= -v str="(std::vector<" '
    BEGIN{ lgth=length(str) }
    start=index($0,str) {
       cnt = 1
       for(i=(start+lgth);(i<=NF) && (cnt!=0);i++) {
          if ($i == "<") cnt++
          if ($i == ">") cnt--
       }
       $0 = substr($0,1,i-1) " const&" substr($0,i)
    }1' "$file" > tmp &&
    mv tmp "$file"
done
```

That won't work if your file name contains newlines but you should just fix those if you have them anyway.

Comment: On Mac, one needs to use additional -E to enable extended (modern) regular expressions: sed -E -i ...

Comment: @Mr.Napik True but none of the sed scripts above use EREs so that wouldn't be required.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle your simple and complex cases separately with different regular expressions.  Regular expressions cannot count nested items and account for that.

Replace with no nesting: `\(std\:\:vector\<([^\<\>]*)\>`

Then replace with single nesting: `\(std\:\:vector\<([^\<\>]*\<[^\<\>]*\>[^\<\>]*)\>`